# how to use variable in src ( Angular2 and Videojs )

Tags: angular, youtube, video.js

i have code

```
<video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264" controls data-setup='{
    "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/nyMkLwSyOVQ" }], "youtube": { "playlist": "2_HXUhShhmY,lLJf9qJHR3E" } }'>
</video>
```

it's work !! 
but i need to use variable in my component.ts replace link youtube 
(https://www.youtube.com/embed/nyMkLwSyOVQ)

like that

> //my variable in component.ts
>
> ```
> src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/nyMkLwSyOVQ";
> ```

```
<video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264" controls data-setup='{
    "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": {{src}} }], "youtube": { "playlist": "2_HXUhShhmY,lLJf9qJHR3E" } }'>
</video>
```

or

```
<video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264" controls data-setup={{data-setup}}
</video>
```

thank for your help

Comment: Normally your {{src}} variable should be the string holding the url to the video

Comment: can you write example for me please
i try it so much way

Comment: Do you want to use video.js or it does not matter if you do not use it? Normally you would import a utube video with iframe. Otherwise try [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(src)" by importing DomSanitizer in your .ts